# Can't do post with curl and ApiKeyAuthentication in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am using tastyPie 0.9.11 to create a RESTful API.

I got the API working ok, but then when I added APIKeyAuthentication I couldn't get the POST request to work.

I have set authentication/authorization in my resource meta as:

```
authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
authorization= Authorization()
```

and I have manually added an API key in the admin site for user admin, with key 1234567890.

When I do a GET it works ok (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/application/?format=json&username=admin&api_key=1234567890 )

However when I try to do a POST using curl:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Authorization: ApiKey admin:1234567890" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"user": "/api/v1/user/1/", "title":"api test application"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/application/
```

I get a 401 not authorized error.

I am following the documentation by adding the Authorization header, but maybe there is something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Update: it works if I use:           `curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"principle_investigator": "/api/v1/user/1/", "title":"api test application"}' "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/application/?username=admin&api_key=1234567890"` but can anyone help me understand why the headers option doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the ApiKey via header was added after v0.9.11. It will be in the v0.9.12 release.